# Getting 500 error with Django via Ajax request, even though Django receives the request and is returning data

Tags: python, django

I have a click function that calls the Ajax request as shown to a url defined in urls.py. I can see that django is getting the data because I have print statements in views.py which print the data that will be passed back to frontend, but I end up getting this error:  "GET /comment-data/?asset=total&timestamp=1654957681 HTTP/1.1" 500 145.

If anyone's run into this before, much help is appreciated!

[Ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG3uZ.png)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGWeM.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXusv.png) (yes I know I have a bunch of unused variables)

Comment: when you go to the url manually what do you see?

Comment: Do you send a CSRF token? `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'`

Comment: @JohnDoe i doubt this is a form submission, he doesn't have form variable in view

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]

Comment: It simply says 'Server Error (500)' on the page

Comment: Update: the request works when the returned data is empty, or rather when no submissions or comments are found.